# Hiding a `Component` image within a Javascript `<Canvas>` Within an IF/ELSE statment

Tags: javascript, canvas

**Hi,** So i'm currently designing a **Javascript** game for my coding subject at school and have encountered a slight hiccup. The point at the moment is to get the Key and get to the end zone inorder to stop the timer in the shortest time possible... When your touching the key at the moment the alert keeps poping up becuase the `IfTouching` statment is just looping so id like to hide the key if its being touched and im not sure how to do so? this is the Bits of Code that are relivant;

```
function startGame() {
    myGameArea.start();
    cleararray()
    myBackground = new component(650, 375, "img/MAP.png", 0, 0, "image");
    myGamePiece = new component(60, 60, "img/forward.gif", 38, 160, "image");
    myHitBox = new component(275, 20, "img/hitbox.png", 250, 240, "image");
    myHitBox1 = new component(30, 180, "img/hitbox.png", 250, 240, "image");
    myHitBox2 = new component(280, 25, "img/hitbox.png", 0, 115, "image");
    myHitBox3 = new component(30, 140, "img/hitbox.png", 120, 111, "image");
    myHitBox4 = new component(145, 25, "img/hitbox.png", 375, 115, "image");
    myHitBox5 = new component(30, 140, "img/hitbox.png", 375, 0, "image");
    item1 = new component(50,50, "img/key.png", 430,40, "image");
}
```

**The Item id Like to HIDE is the `item1`** (The last one) which has the image path of `img/key.png`

the hit detection is this:

```
this.touching = function(otherthing) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherthing.x;
    var otherright = otherthing.x + (otherthing.width);
    var othertop = otherthing.y;
    var otherbottom = otherthing.y + (otherthing.height);
    var touch = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
        touch = false;
    }
    return touch;

}
```

And then the If statment is here (This is where the **Hide** Function needs to go)

```
else if (myGamePiece.touching(item1))  {

        alert("You have the KEY!!!! Head to the gate and stop the timer!");
        addTurnToArray(); 
     }
```

If you know how to do this PLEASE help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a visibility flag to your object:

```
function component( /* ... */ ) {
  // ...
  this.visible = true;
}
```

Then in the hit test check for visibility as well:

```
else if (myGamePiece.touching(item1) && item1.visible)  {
    item1.visible = false;    // hide
    alert("You have the KEY!!!! Head to the gate and stop the timer!");
    addTurnToArray(); 
}
```

The same flag is then used when the code renders the frame, to exclude it.